# Redirecting after JQuery AJAX request from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So when the login button is clicked, I use JQuery POST method to get data from login.php if the login was successful or not. If it wasn't (no user found), then it correctly displays the message.

But when I want to redirect the user (user exists), it prints out the whole webpage into that one DIV.

The JQuery after button is pressed:

```
$(function(){

$("#login-form").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var name = $('#inputName').val();
    var password = $('#inputPassword').val();

    $.post("login.php", 
    {
        name: name,
        password: password
    },
    function(data)
    {
        $("#resultDiv").hide().html(data).fadeIn(1000).effect( "shake", {direction:"up",times:2, distance:10}, 750 );
    });
});
});
```

If login not successful, it displays. But when I want to redirect, doesen't work:

```
if(!$row) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top:25px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-align:center;">Invalid <strong>username</strong> or <strong>password</strong>.</div>';
} else {

  $line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

  $_SESSION['IP'] = $line["IP"];
  $_SESSION['ID'] = $line["ID"];
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

  header("location:choose.php");
}
```

So when the user logs in, how do I just redirect him? Don't want to display anything.

Comment: Why not redirect with `JavaScript`? `echo` `true` and check if the returned value equals `true`, if it does then redirect.

Comment: Why not remove the ajax entirely? It seems to just be complicating things in this case.

Comment: Because I dont want the page to reload if login wasn't successful (message is displayed by JQuery if it isn't).

Comment: You can still echo error messages through php after page reload for unsuccessful login combination

Comment: but then he wouldn't get the pretty fadein+shake and force the user to wait a second or two before continuing.

Comment: `$('div#errors').fadeIn();` will do it, i use similar thing with flashing notification messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login script won't redirect the whole page the way you have it, it is only redirecting the AJAX request, so it makes sense that the whole page ends up in the resultDiv.

Your success function should look at the data returned before it applies the data to the resultDiv html().

I found it easier to make the login response a JSON data set, which makes it much easier to grab:

```
if(data.loggedIn==true) {
  window.location = data.location;
} else {}
```

You can also keep the resultDiv for errors, it is just:

```
$("#resultDiv").hide().html(data.errorMsg)...
```

For the php side:

```
if(!$row) {
  echo '{loggedIn:false,errorMsg:"<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" style=\"margin-top:25px; margin-bottom: 0px; text-align:center;\">Invalid <strong>username</strong> or <strong>password</strong>.</div>"}';
} else {

  $line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

  $_SESSION['IP'] = $line["IP"];
  $_SESSION['ID'] = $line["ID"];
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

  echo '{loggedIn:true,location:"choose.php"}';

}
```

I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: Used JSON to send the result back to javascript - working now.